# how to use 'for' loop to create multiple figures, not all data in one figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot some statistics results for each region. I have nested 'for' loops, where in the inner loop it generates the statistics, in the outer loop it selects the regions and plot the respective statistic results. Not sure why my code plots data from all regions into the same figure, not one figure for a region.

```
Yrstat = []
for j in Regionlist:
    for i in Yrlist:
            dfnew = df.loc[(df['Yr']==i)&(df['Region']==j)]
            if not dfnew.empty:
                #calculate the confidence interval and mean for data in each year
                CI = scipy.stats.norm.interval(alpha=0.95, loc=np.mean(dfnew['FluxTot']), scale=scipy.stats.sem(dfnew['FluxTot']))
                list(CI)
                mean = np.mean (dfnew['FluxTot'])
                Yrstat.append((i, mean, CI[0], CI[1]))
        
    #convert stats list to a dataframe
    yrfullinfo = pd.DataFrame(Yrstat, columns = ['Yr', 'mean', 'CI-','CI+'])

    #making figures
    fig, ax =plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(yrfullinfo['Yr'], yrfullinfo['mean'], label = 'mean')
    ax.plot(yrfullinfo['Yr'], yrfullinfo['CI-'], label = '95%CI')
    ax.plot(yrfullinfo['Yr'], yrfullinfo['CI+'], label = '95%CI')
    ax.legend()
   
    #exporting figures
    filename = "C:/Users/Christina/Desktop/python test/Summary in {}.png". format (j)
    fig.savefig(filename)
    plt.close(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't the figure, the script saves a `png` file for each region in an own plot which is correct. The problem is your data.
You intitialize `Yrstat=[]` outside of both loops. Then you append data to it in every step of the inner loop (and also all outer loops) and plot the data of the "new" DataFrame `yrfullinfo`. This DataFrame grows bigger with each iteration.
You need to create a new list of values for each Region, that's why I moved the list `Yrstat` in the outer loop to get reinitialized for every region.

```
for j in Regionlist:    
    Yrstat = []
    for i in Yrlist:
        dfnew=dfmerge.loc[(dfmerge['Yr']==i)&(dfmerge['Region']==j)]
        if not dfnew.empty:
            #get all statistics for data in each year
            CI = st.norm.interval(alpha=0.95, loc=np.mean(dfnew['FluxTot']), scale=st.sem(dfnew['FluxTot']))
            list(CI)
            mean = np.mean (dfnew['FluxTot'])
            Yrstat.append((j, i, mean, CI[0], CI[1]))
```

Comment: hi Rabinzel, thanks for your answer, I tried your solution but the problem is still there. Data are all plotted in the same figure. I added plt.figure() between two 'for' loop, I also added plt.clf() at the end of each plotting. They both do not work...

Comment: hm, I had another look in my old scripts now because I remembered I had a similar task and I did it like this. Instead of `fig,ax=plt.subplots()` I had 2 lines of code, `fig=plt.figure()` and the next `ax=plt.subplot()` (with plural s, only subplot). place them lines also in the outer loop after `for j in Regionlist` and remove `fig, ax = ...` in the inner loop. Maybe you want to try that

Comment: no, not working either... I gave up and worked around it by using the double 'for' loop to get statistics of all regions, and adding another single 'for' loop to the end only to plot figures. This combo works fine but is not beautiful at all.

Comment: sorry, too bad I couldn't help. I guess I delete my answer then. Is your data some how sensitive for public or could you share it? I'd like to test it with your code and find out why this isn't working.

Comment: wow, that would be wonderful, how can I send you my code and data. I have prepared them

Comment: you could just upload it somewhere (I found e.g easyupload.io) and share the link here. Add all relevant parts of your code too (I guess in the question here is just a small snippet)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10XpIg_6eAQ1Pc2Sudn45t0gH8mWHcOvu/view?usp=sharing see if you can download the zip file, there are two files inside, one .py for the code, one .xlsx for the data, thank you so much Rabinzel!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244603/discussion-between-rabinzel-and-elizabeth).

Comment: I updated my answer. Now it should work